# Sudo password is not working

Tags: login, sudo, password, root

We had to do some configuration to our system in our company and they wanted to do these steps:

1. `sudo vi /etc/pam_radius_auth.conf`
2. Add

   ```
   *****.com ***radius 3
   ```
3. Add `auth sufficient pam_radius_auth.so localifdown` to following files just above `@include common-auth`:

   ```
   /etc/pam.d/login
   /etc/pam.d/sshd
   /etc/pam.d/sudo
   ```
4. Add `try_first_pass` in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

   ```
   auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure
   try_first_pass
   ```

I did two mistakes, first I added the line they said (in step three) to last file and forgot to add it to two first file:

```
/etc/pam.d/login
/etc/pam.d/sshd
```

Second I added the whole line in step 4 to the end of the file instead of just concatenating to:

```
 auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

I can not sudo any more after I restarted my system. I need to modify those files and without sudo I don't know how I should do it. I tried the recovery mode in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) and no luck. In the recovery mode it prompts me for root password and none of the password is working. 
I still can login to my account but apparently my sudo user is mis configured. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please contact your IT department.

Comment: @muru thank you very much. I’ll try this first thing in the morning.